# Simplifying Boolean expression (Distributing)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am working on a boolean function which needs to be simplified to minimize logic gates. The function is (a + b + NOT C)(NOT a and NOT b + c). I am confused at the step which I have ended at in the photo. My intuition is that the outcome would be 0 because of the two negate other and are anded. Please let provide any advice on this.

Comment: I don't see a photo.

Comment: The [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) negation of `(a + b + NOT c)` is `(NOT a and NOT b and c)`. Slightly different from the expression in your question.

Comment: I do not bother with photos.   They are usually too glary.   Do you mean not (b + c) or (not b) + c?  I would think it the latter.   That is not a function.  It is a Boolean expression.

Comment: Sorry the photo is not attached. I also put function when I meant expression. The second part in the bracket is meant to be (not A and not B or C).

Answer (score 1):

The simplified expression is:

```
bc + ac + !a!b!c
```

The Karnaugh map:

```
             bc
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   0  | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
a     +---+---+---+---+
   1  | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```

---

Analytically, this can be seen in the following steps:

Original expression:

```
(a + b + !c)(!a and !b + c)
```

Parentheses multiplied:

```
a(!a !b) + ac + b(!a !b) + bc + !c(!a!b) + c!c
```

Conjunctive terms with negated literals removed:

```
ac + bc + !a!b!c
```